# How to split docker layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile looks like

```
RUN echo "Downloading huge file" && \
  wget   http://server/huge.tar.gz  && \
  echo "Extracting huge file" && \
  tar xzf huge.tar.gz  && \
  huge/install /opt/myinstall && \
  rm -rf huge*
```

Actually, I am

1. Downloading some third party installation package
2. Unpacking
3. Running install
4. Removing installation files

Docker build succeeds  and I can use my new container.

Problem starts when I am pushing to Amazon Container registry.

Push is  rejected because last layer is huge ( ~about 20G).

20G is a real size of installation, so I can do a little to decrease it.

My question is how can I split a layer to some smaller layers to accommodate Amazon layer size limit?

Comment: You can pass a path from within the tar to `tar` to only extract some directories or files.  Maybe you can use that option to run multiple phases of untar?  Basically build the directory in pieces over multiple run commands.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the list of directories deb files plan to create ?

Answer (score 3):

A new layer is created on each dockerfile instruction. So the solution is to split the `RUN` command into multiple `RUN` commands. However, I am not sure that this solution will work in your case if the tar is very big, as one of the layers will contain the tar. Nonetheless, you should try this approach.

```
RUN wget http://server/huge.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf huge.tar.gz
RUN huge/install /opt/myinstall && \
RUN rm -rf huge*
```

Another alternative is to use [docker multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages). The idea is to install the tar in a separate container and just copy the installation directory to you container:

```
FROM ... as installer
RUN echo "Downloading huge file" && \
  wget   http://server/huge.tar.gz  && \
  echo "Extracting huge file" && \
  tar xzf huge.tar.gz  && \
  huge/install /opt/myinstall && \
  rm -rf huge*

FROM ...
COPY --from=installer /opt/myinstall /opt/myinstall
...
```

That way you will only have one layer in your image which only copies the installation.

Comment: Great idea with multistage build! Unfortunately , installation directory is >10G so, I need to split /opt/myinstall is some way...

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem image which has a layer size>7GB.
Much unfortunately, my huge file is a single binary file.

First, I use `split` command to make file parts:

```sh
split -b 1000M huge.bin part_
```

In `Dockerfile`, replace huge file copy with:

```
ADD data/part_aa /data/
ADD data/part_ab /data/
ADD data/part_ac /data/
ADD data/part_ad /data/
ADD data/part_ae /data/
ADD data/part_af /data/
ADD data/part_ag /data/
```

In `entrypoint.sh` whitch is startup script, Add following command lines to `combine`:

```
cd /data
MODEL_FILE="huge.bin"
if [ ! -f "$MODEL_FILE" ]; then
  echo "combine model file parts, this may take 5 minutes"
  cat part_* > $MODEL_FILE
  echo "combine model file parts done"
fi
```

For less copy and download, use `wget` to speed up in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_aa
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_ab
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_ac
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_ad
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_ae
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_af
RUN wget -P /data http://192.168.1.111/files/data/part_ag
```

- WARNING: `wget` only cache url sum but file sum whitch `Add` does